# Wordpress finding a specific link to edit it

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hyperlink

I was handed down a website to edit with wordpress and I no basically nothing about wordpress.

I am trying to edit a link in the front page of my website however I just can't find this link. I have looked through the every page's PHP (You can look through the PHPs of your site in HTML per page in wordpress) and I just can't seem to find it.

It isn't in the Header.php or the footer.php or even the archive.php I've looked everywhere. It is basically just a link in the middle of the front page that I can't seem to pinpoint (See image, link is in the red circle).

Please help me, is there a quick way to find this link? Or do you know where this link would be placed in the wordpress dashboard editor?

[image]

[image]

UPDATE 12/06/14

I found this code in the Frontpage.PHP

```
<?php`enter code here`
                    foreach ($query as $post) {
                        setup_postdata($post);

                        printf('<div>');
                        printf('<div class="box">');
                        printf('<h4>%s</h4>', $post->post_title);

                        printf('<img src="%s" />', wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_id()), 'full')[0]);

                        printf('<p>%s</p>', get_the_excerpt($post->ID));
                        printf('<a href="%s" class="button">Read more</a>', post_permalink($post->ID));
                        printf('</div>');
                        printf('</div>');
                    }

                    wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
```

Think this is where I have to insert the link I want it to lead to?

Comment: It may be a simple widget in the page body. In a wp-admin console look at 'Appearance'-> 'widgets'

Comment: Is there a search functionality where you can search all the back-end content for text and pieces of code?

Comment: Banzay, no there are no widgets installed I checked that way back.

Comment: Chris, none that I know of.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Hover over the "appearance" link on the left, and you'll see the link "Menus."  Click there, and you can edit the menus that are already made, or create a new one.

Often things in WordPress are entered into the database that is connected to the website, via the WordPress admin area.  The database receives information from your Wordpress admin and that info gets processed via the code in the PHP files, and then displayed on the web page.  That's most likely why you couldn't find the link in your directory of PHP files.

Comment: Thats the thing its not included in any of the two menus of my site. It literally is just dab in the middle of my front page and not in any menu.

Comment: Would it be ok if you provide the address for the site?

Comment: Or can you provide a picture of the admin area?  I see that you're trying to remove a "read more" link.  That must be connected to a widget or some kind of plugin, or something related to the theme.

Comment: well sure, I guess I can do that. But Im not trying to remove the link, I'm trying to change it so that it directs the reader to another page